# how to use dive in wrapper function to enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, styled-components

I want to make a wrapper function which could take a component as an argument and return it in rendered from with theme. Like below one. but it continued to throw error wrapper:

> error :  ShallowWrapper::dive() can only be called on components

```
beforeEach(() => {
      component = shallowWithTheme(<SomeComponent value />);
    });

    test('The text should be something text', () => {
      expect(component.text()).toBe('Something text');
    });
```

Wrapper function **shallowWithTheme**

```
   export const shallowWithTheme = (children, options) => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>, options).dive();
      return wrapper;     
    };
```

[image]

**Edited**

```
export const shallowWithTheme = (children, options) => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>, options);
  const instance = wrapper.root().instance();
  return wrapper.shallow({ context: instance.getChildContext() }).dive();
};
```

**Error:**

```
instance.getChildContext is not a function
```

Update:

After doing hours of finding and hit and trial I ended up using following solution which I don't think is the right way to do it because you have to import your child component in order to find them and access their property. In previous method which is not working with current version. I was able to dive once from root level. So If I have to run a test on two child component I have to use like

```
expect(wrapper.find(SearchButton).dive().props().isDisabled).toBe(false);
          });

expect(wrapper.find(SearchInput).dive().props().isDisabled).toBe(false);
          });
```

**util.js**

```
 export const shallowWithTheme = children => (
      shallow(children, { theme })
    );
```

**test.js**

```
it('should enable the search button while the input is not empty', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowWithTheme(<HomepageSearch />);
    wrapper.setState({ orderSearch: '111' });
        expect(wrapper.find(SearchButton).dive().props().isDisabled).toBe(false);
      });
```

Comment: You want to dive into your children but shallow will not render more than 1 level deep. You'd need to use mount. That said, `ThemeProvider` is not a component, it's more of context provider. You can find some workarounds here: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/624

Comment: @Mrchief I have tried the some method described in the github issue you mention in your comment. I found most of the solution is based on the previous version and seem not working with version 4

Comment: I have added my question to explain what I have tried and what is current issue I am facing.

Comment: Yeah, seems like v4 makes it hard to test. I guess your best bet is to create a mock provider for testing.

Comment: besides it'll not help to solve, it seems to be rootcause: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1647